# order array as of other array php

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.5

Using JFolder:

```
$tree = JFolder::listFolderTree('myfolder');
```

Lists the tree structure like this: (ignore and ignore2 are subfolders inside each folder b,n,v)

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => b
            [fullname] => myfolder/b
            [relname] => myfolder/b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 1
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => n
            [fullname] => myfolder/n
            [relname] => myfolder/n
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 4
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 4
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => v
            [fullname] => myfolder/v
            [relname] => myfolder/v
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent] => 7
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 7
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )

)
```

So we can see the ordering of the folders: 0 has name "b" 1 has name "n" and 2 has name "v".

Now I want to order them in user defined order from the array:

```
$user_defined_array = [b,v,n];
```

So now the $tree ordering should `0 => b, 1 => v and 2 => n` and if the user changes the the array like `[n,v,b]` then ordering should be like that.

For example if user defined array like `[b,v,n]` the resulting array should look like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => b
            [fullname] => myfolder/b
            [relname] => myfolder/b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent] => 1
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parent] => 1
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )



    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => v
            [fullname] => myfolder/v
            [relname] => myfolder/v
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent] => 4
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent] => 4
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent] => 0
            [name] => n
            [fullname] => myfolder/n
            [relname] => myfolder/n
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [parent] => 7
            [name] => ignore
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent] => 7
            [name] => ignore2
            [fullname] => myfolder/ignore2
            [relname] => myfolder/ignore2
        )

)
```

I hope question is clear and I hope there is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as I understand your question

```
$user_defined_array = array('b','v','n');
$newarr = array();
$i=0;$k=1;
foreach($user_defined_array as $a){
        foreach($tree as $b){
                if($k==0 && !in_array($b['name'],$user_defined_array)){
                        $newarr[$i] = $b;$i++;
                }else{$k=1;}
                if($b['name']==$a) {
                        $newarr[$i] = $b;
                        $k=0;$i++;
                }

        }

}
var_dump($newarr);
```

This will output an array based on your new user defined array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is excluding other arrays ignore and ignore2 folder not listing.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I was able to solve it with one of my friends help. Please check the new solution.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I already checked in localhost its working fine. What result you are getting?

Comment: Yes. Its working fine. Thank you very much and your friend too.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Sometimes I take his help and sometimes he takes mine. We both are good friends. This one was our combines effort.

Comment: Very good. I would also like to work with such team if possible.